# Residue of a function ith different poles

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

I don't understand the part I have highlighted in green.

Comment: Is the residue not the coefficient of the $1/z$ term? Or in this case, $1/(z+k)$?

Comment: this is +/- the definition of the residue  : $\frac{C}{z-a}$ has a pole of order $1$ and residue $C$ at $z=a$

Comment: (hence it follows that $A_k = \prod_{m=0,m \ne k}^n \frac{1}{k-m} = \ldots$)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Equation $(0.14)$ in the OP, we have

$$\prod_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{z+k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{A_k}{z+k} \tag 1$$

Now, multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $z+\ell$ and take the limit as $z\to -\ell$.

Then, we find that

$$\begin{align}
A_\ell &= \prod_{k=0,k\ne \ell}^n \frac{1}{k-\ell}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(-\ell)(1-\ell)(2-\ell)\cdots (1)(2)\cdots (n-\ell)}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(-1)^\ell\ell!(n-\ell)!} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ yields the coveted equality

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!\,z+k} =\prod_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{z+k}$$

And we are done!